# Why is this happening while writing an Excel in Java

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, xls

Ok, basically i'm trying to write 3 columns and N number of rows simultaneously while iterating. The problem is that 2 of the 3 columns are written with the values... even though they appear in the System.out.println(), are not being written in the Excel. Here's the code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < versionsToGraph.length; i++) {           
                    List<WsCallEntry> wfCalls = allCalls.get(i);
                    int cant = -1;
                    if(!wfCalls.isEmpty()) {                            
                        for (WsCallEntry wsCallEntry : wfCalls) {   
                            String x = wsCallEntry.getKey();
                            int y = wsCallEntry.getValue();
                            cant++;
                            if(versionsToGraph[i].equals("15.6")) {
                                System.out.println(x + " " + y + " will be added.");
                                XSSFSheet sheet = (XSSFSheet) wb.getSheetAt(0);     
                                XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(27+cant);                                 

                                XSSFCell celly = row.createCell(10); 

                                celly.setCellValue(y);
                            }else{
                                if(versionsToGraph[i].equals("15.9")) {

                                    System.out.println(x + " " + y + " will be added.");
                                    XSSFSheet sheet = (XSSFSheet) wb.getSheetAt(0);     
                                    XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(27+cant);                                 

                                    XSSFCell celly = row.createCell(11); 

                                    celly.setCellValue(y);
                                }
                            }                       


                            xValues.add(x); 


                        }                           


                        Collections.sort(xValues, new StringComparator());

                }                           
                }                       
                ArrayList<String> newList = eliminarRepetidos(xValues); 
                int cant = 0;
                for (String newlist : newList) {
                    String x = newlist;
                    XSSFSheet sheet = (XSSFSheet) wb.getSheetAt(0);         
                    XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(27+cant);                                 
                    XSSFCell cellx = row.createCell(9); 
                    cellx.setCellValue(x);
                    cant++;
                }               
            }
```

So, it should add in this part of the code, the 15.6, 15.9 Y values, and in the last foreach writes the X values in the Excel.
What i'm getting is X values and 15.9 Y values. What am I not getting the 15.6 ones? :(

(from the comment)
I´m using these

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell; 
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook; 
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory; 
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell; 
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow; 
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
```

Comment: what java package are you using to create your xls?

Comment: I´m using these
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;

Comment: Beacuse i'm editing a created XLSX file, that's why i needed to use XSSF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating the same row on every iteration of `versionsToGraph`, you are erasing what was added in previously.

```
XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(27+cant);
```

You should be doing

```
sheet.getRow(27+cant);
```

after the first iteration.

Answer (score 1):

So, how many instances of `wfCalls` are there?  And how many of those instances of `versionToGraph` are equal to 15.6 or 15.9?  If `cant` is being incremented many times because the versions don't match, your rows in the sheet will probably be far pasted the first visible rows in Excel.  I would double check the row numbers you're writing to.

Comment: there's only one wfCalls instance. The thing is, inside of the wfCalls are X, Y pair values. The first "half" of the list is 15.6, and the other half is 15.9.
For now it works for 15.6, 15.9 and both at the same time. 
I've tried commenting for example 15.9, and writes 15.6 and X values, if i comment the 15.6 part, it writes 15.9 and X, if i comment X part, it writes 15.6 and 15.9, wtf :(